# How do I add extra years to a time series dataset using tsappend?

Tags: stata

Consider the following example code:

```
clear
set obs 20

generate t = 2000 + _n

tsset t, yearly
tsappend, last(2025) tsfmt(ty)
```

This crashes with the error below:

```
unknown function ty()
r(133);
```

However, according to [the Stata 15 documentation for tsappend](https://www.stata.com/manuals15/tstsappend.pdf), the `ty` argument to the `tsfmt` option should be supported (even though there is not actually a `ty()` function in Stata).

[image: relevant section of the documentation for tsappend]

I know I can do this with a little math and either the `add` option to `tsappend` or, separately, the `expand` command, but I am trying to figure out why the documentation does not function as described.

I am using Stata/MP 15.1 for Unix (Linux 64-bit x86-64), Revision 26 Aug 2019 but I get the same error on Stata/MP 15.1 for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The help file and manual of the `tsappend` command in all recent versions of Stata clearly states:

> "*tsfmt(string) specifies the name of the Stata time-series function to use in converting the date specified in last() to an integer.  The function names are
>           tc (clock), tC (Clock), td (daily), tw (weekly), tm (monthly), tq (quarterly), and th (half-yearly).*"

The functions `tc()`, `td()` etc. are all convenience functions in Stata jargon. Given that no `ty()` convenience function exists, the item in the list you present is likely a typo.

A look in the manuals shows that the `%ty` format is associated with the following functions:

- `y()`
- `year()`
- `yearly()`

Here, the `y()` function (last table item in [*Building SIFs from components*](https://www.stata.com/manuals/ddatetime.pdf#dDatetimeSyntaxBuildingSIFsfromcomponents)) can be used:

```
clear
set obs 20

generate t = 2000 + _n

tsset t, yearly
tsappend, last(2025) tsfmt(y)
```

```
list

     +------+
     |    t |
     |------|
  1. | 2001 |
  2. | 2002 |
  3. | 2003 |
  4. | 2004 |
  5. | 2005 |
     |------|
  6. | 2006 |
  7. | 2007 |
  8. | 2008 |
  9. | 2009 |
 10. | 2010 |
     |------|
 11. | 2011 |
 12. | 2012 |
 13. | 2013 |
 14. | 2014 |
 15. | 2015 |
     |------|
 16. | 2016 |
 17. | 2017 |
 18. | 2018 |
 19. | 2019 |
 20. | 2020 |
     |------|
 21. | 2021 |
 22. | 2022 |
 23. | 2023 |
 24. | 2024 |
 25. | 2025 |
     +------+
```

For learning purposes, inspection of the source code for `tsappend` can confirm why this in fact works.

In the `_tsappend3` sub-command, which handles this combination of options we see that:

```
local lastt `=`tsfmt'(`last')'
```

For `tsfmt()` specified as `y` we then get:

```
local lastt `=y(2025)'
```

This is equal to `2025` - type `display y(2025)` to confirm.

Further down the code we also see the following:

```
gen `add' = max((`lastt' - `tmax') / `delta' + 1, 1) if `touse'
```

The generated variable is then used to `expand` the dataset.